# AngularJS simple hello world and style not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am quit new in AngularJS and am trying to display a simple "hello world". Instead it displays: {{"hello" + " world"}}.

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('store', []);
```

**defaultLayout.ftl.html**

```
<html ng-app="store">
<head>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<p>{{"hello" + " you"}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Folder structure**

assets/css

- bootstrap.min.css

views/layout

- defaultLayout.ftl.html
- app.js

In addition I don´t have any style in the web page. Does someone know where are my problems??

Comment: working http://plnkr.co/edit/q7T2c0kV97FTJ3nGKSMi?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I understand, you have to include the folder name in the `src` and `href` path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="views/layout/app.js"></script>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Thank you!! that solve my problem about the style!!but I already have the problem with angular, the output is still <p>{{"hello" + " you"}}</p>.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I manage to solve the problem. I don´t know why but it works if I move app.js to assets folder and write this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/app.js"></script>:
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score -1):

Please use google CDN:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
```

You don't go inside your assets directory to fetch bootstrap